# How to know primary and secondary DNS servers for IPv6?

Tags: dns, ipv6, isp

In my router's WAN page, it says my Primary and Secondary DNS servers are `84.xx.xx.xx` which belong to my ISP's DNS servers. However, my router is connected to IPv6 and lists my DNSv6 server as `fe80::1` which is just the default IPv6 for LAN.

So just like IPv4, is there any way for me to know which Primary and Secondary DNS servers are used by my ISP for IPv6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach a DNS server over IPv4 and still ask it for the IPv6 address for a given hostname, and vice-versa. So it's completely possible that your ISP is only giving you IPv4-reachable DNS servers, but those are still the servers to which you'll be sending your AAAA (IPv6 address) queries.

Comment: Thanks Spiff. I always had my doubts about what you said, but now it all make sense. :)